# How can I access the full functionality of a Japanese Apple keyboard on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am currently using a Japanese Apple keyboard (Model A1048) on Windows 8.1. I have two issues with this setup. The first issue is that they keyboard is detected as a US layout keyboard, which causes issues with many of the symbol keys. The previous issue can be partly remedied [by editing the registry, as detailed here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927824). But that still leaves me with another problem (the focus of this post): the conversion and kana keys don’t work.

Answer (score 0):

after you instal the language pack, activate the keyboard layout

more from the internet

This varies from computer to computer, and some OS vendors have striven to provide a consistent user interface regardless of the type of keyboard being used. On non-Japanese keyboards, option (right alt )- or control- key sequences can perform all of the tasks mentioned

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_input_methods

Comment: Activating the layout hasn't been an issue; it's getting all the extra keys to be recognised. I would imaging that with most Japanese keyboards this wouldn't be an issue, but it seems that the Apple version has some of the keys mapped differently than is standard.

Comment: use a third party software to add the extra keys on your keyboard, just google it, this should be solved days ago

Answer (score -1):

not sure if is the right answer ( never had a Japanese keyboard ), but try this :

1. install language pack , that should include keyboard layout
2. check  for a driver from the manufacturer
3. use a third party software to edit the keys on your keyboard

Comment: I've tried installing the Japanese language pack, but it has no effect. I doubt Apple has released drivers for Windows for their keyboards (but if they have one I would appreciate a link). The third party key remapping could work, but I haven't found one that allows be to map to the kana or conversion keys, and even if I could map the keys directly, I'm not sure what values Windows expects.